# How to handle huge argument to send from bash script to a PHP job

Tags: php, bash, shell

I have a Bash script from which I am trying to send git log information to PHP which processes it.

```
php parse_git_commits_info.php --git_log_info="$COMMIT_LOG_INFO"
```

I am getting Argument list too long error when git log info is pretty huge. How can I fix this?

Comment: Put that log info in a file and pass that in instead. There's limits on what you can put on the command-line.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am a bit new to shell scripting. May I know how can I pass a file as an argument once I save that log info into a file ?

Comment: It depends on what you're passing it in to. Each command-line tool, be it `php` or `git` or `curl` has different ways of doing it.

Comment: I should be able to pass the file into a php job which reads the text in that file line by line and parses it.

Comment: PHP can read in files if you want, absolutely. It's up to you to parse those command-line arguments.